# Need to click on the button

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I need to click on button on IE and I have used both the cases but none worked for me

```java
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Existing Customer']")).click();
```

or

```java
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Existing Customer')]")).click();
```

or

```java
WebElement obj = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Existing Customer']")).click();

Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.moveToElement(obj).build().perform();
```

[HTML Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piSfr.jpg)

Comment: Seems to me it's a Dropdown. Can provide the following information : 1. Provide more HTML DOM. 2. Can you confirm if it is a modal Dropdown ? 3. Provide a screenshot of the Dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

In place of "button" tag you can use * symbol, it can represent any tag.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Existing Customer']")).click();
```

[or]

```
WebElement obj = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Existing Customer']"));

Actions act = new Actions(driver);

act.doubleClick(obj).build().perform();
```